How Can I Stop a Bird from Knocking on My Window Every Morning?
There is a bird that visits every day at 5:30 AM and knocks on my window. This has been happening for months, and while it was cute at first, it's now incredibly annoying and I can't stand it anymore. I researched why birds do this and learned that they see their reflection in the window and think it's a rival, so they try to defend their territory.
I don't want to hurt the bird, but I want it to stop. I tried using cardboard with sticky tape, but the wind blew it away.
I've seen temporary frosting on glass windows, with names or hearts drawn on them. I'd like to try that method. Does anyone know what this is called and if I can make it myself?

Show the situation, please. "A window" isn't a helpful description, and the general layout of the area would inform good answers.

Tape a picture of a cat to the window.

or a pic of a hawk!

@DelphicOracle i tried that, i put an owl pic but did notthing to that bird

Maybe, @DelphicOracle, maybe not.

Put the hawk (or kitty) decal on the outside of the glass, so the bird does not see its reflection.

@DrMoishePippik i did, and the bird was not scared. kept coming doing the same everyday.

Try putting a lamp on the inside of the window.  If it's not dark inside, the glass won't work as a mirror.  Easy to try; you probably have a lamp already.

Yes, the bird is seeing its reflection in the window and trying to defend its territory. If it sees what it thinks is a larger bird or one that is a predator to it or its young, it won't attack and might just move out of the neighborhood.
A quick search at a major online retailer's web site* for "anti bird strike window decals" revealed dozens of options for stickers of large birds of prey. One of these stickers, applied to the inside of the window, is likely going to be sufficient to deter your new neighbor from waking you up. You might need to move it occasionally or add another sticker if your friend gets feisty.
Often times, a plastic owl statue on a pedestal outside the window might do the trick, as well.
*Any retailer of your choice is fine, no recommendations implied or intended. You might even find some at a local garden center.

We have an addition the previous owners of the house put on; it has a cathedral ceiling with two large triangular panes of glass. Birds would fly into the glass. Silhouettes of raptors, wings spread, affixed to the glass didn't stop that from happening.
There are reflective "bird deterrent" pinwheels you might be able to affix to the outside wall or sill, perhaps on a rod of some kind. Maybe even a dollar-store plastic one might work.
And those owl and hawk statues don't work. I wasn't fast enough with my camera to catch it, but soon after we tried one, there was a bird perched on its head, and it even had some "motion-detection" that caused its eyes to flash.

"Cling" or "Static" stickers (no glue) are a cheap and effortless way to try to stop this.  Try birds.   You can get frosted film that sticks that way too, but laying it bubble free and cutting it to the edges is a PIA and then it blocks your view.
Making it harder to perch is another approach, using string, wires, anti-pigeon spikes, etc.  Hanging strands of tinsel outside near the window apparently dissuades some birds from approaching.  All of these things are slightly more cost and effort, and uglier so I wouldn't start with them.
Moving on up ... a life-like owl decoy with solar powered rotating head and glowing eyes and motion-sensor trigger.   Mount that on the wall near the window.  It might scare the birds off.  Or not.
